# Tab is skipping on certain iterations

Tags: python, list, csv

I am trying to print a list of lists and want the different columns to have a tab. It works for all except lines 3 and 5. Cannot figure out why!

```
import csv
FILENAME = "BaseballPlayers.csv"


#def display_lineup():

player_list = []
with open(FILENAME, newline="") as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    for row in reader:
        player_list.append(row)
    
for i in range(len(player_list)):
    player = player_list[i]
    print(str(i+1) + ". " + player[0]+ "\t" + player[1]+ "\t" +player[2]+ "\t" +player[3])
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a problem with the tab being skipped, but a fundamental quirk of how tab works. Tabbing takes you *to the next **tab stop***, which might not always be the same location depending on what came before. When your player's name is less than 5 characters, e.g. in "Tony", the *next tab stop* is one space after "Tony" ends.

If I copy the output from your code over to a text editor that shows me the whitespace characters, this is what it looks like:

[image]

Evidently, the tabs are *there*, but not *"big enough"*.

A solution is to pad spaces to increase your column values to a maximum list, and *then* use tabs.

```
max_col_width = None
player_list = []
with open(FILENAME, newline="") as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    for row in reader:
        if max_col_width is None:
            # This is the first row, set the lengths of each column as the max
            max_col_width = [len(c) for c in row]
        else:
            # For each column, the max is the larger of the 
            # existing max and the current column's length
            max_col_width = [max(m, len(c)) for m, c in zip(max_col_width, row)]
        player_list.append(row)
```

`zip` takes two iterables and iterates over them simultaneously, so `for m, c in zip(max_col_width, row)` is the same as doing

```
for i in len(row):
    m = max_col_width[i]
    c = row[i]
```

If we print `max_col_width`, we can see the values: `[7, 2, 3, 3]`. So we need to pad every element in the first column to a length of 7, every element in the second column to a length of 2, and so on.
We can use [`str.ljust()`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_ljust.asp) to left-align all strings before printing them:

```
for i, player in enumerate(player_list):
    player = player_list[i]
    print(str(i+1) + ". " + player[0].ljust(max_col_width[0]) + "\t" + player[1].ljust(max_col_width[1]) + "\t" +player[2].ljust(max_col_width[2]) + "\t" +player[3].ljust(max_col_width[3]))
```

Or a more Pythonic way of the above is to use a generator and `str.join()` along with `ljust`

```
for i, player in enumerate(player_list):
    player = player_list[i]
    print(str(i+1) + ". " + "\t".join(p.ljust(l) for p, l in zip(player, max_col_width)))
```

Now we have spaces extending the length of each name to the maximum length, and the tabbing works like we want it to.

[image]

As text, we get the following output:

```
1. Trevor   SS  588 173
2. Garrett  2B  299 74 
3. Tony     C   535 176
4. Hunter   RF  580 182
5. Ian      CF  443 113
...
```

Of course since you're already padding things, you could eliminate the `\t` character altogether and use any number of spaces instead (in my example below, 4) to get consistent spacing between columns.

```
for i, player in enumerate(player_list):
    player = player_list[i]
    print(str(i+1) + ". " + (" " * 4).join(p.ljust(l) for p, l in zip(player, max_col_width)))
    # Or alternatively, 
    # print(str(i+1) + ". " + "".join(p.ljust(l + 4) for p, l in zip(player, max_col_width)))
```

[image]